# Center focal point of image without knowing container dimension

Tags: css

I get different images with focal points from a cms and want to display them with `object-fit: cover` and positioned in such a way that the given focal point is as close as possible to the center and there's no whitespace on any side. However, the container dimensions are dynamic and therefore unknown in the CSS. Is there a CSS only solution (without the use of size observers with javascript) for this problem?

I know that the following code (red border) produces a somewhat acceptable solution. But it's not exactly what I want since `object-position` with percentages is relative to the container. So the focal point is not in the center. To quote the mdn web docs:

> `background-position: 25% 75%` means the spot on the image that is 25% from the left and 75% from the top will be placed at the spot of the container that is 25% from the container's left and 75% from the container's top.

In this example I have a 640x960 px image and want to focus on the moon (320, 213 px). For the red bordered image I calculated the percentages by simply dividing the values. But I want the green bordered image as a result.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.a img {
  object-position: 50% 22.19%;
}

.b img {
  /* Values found out by trial and error or by calculating with the help of the container dimensions */
  object-position: 50% 8%;
}

.a, .b {
  border: 2px solid red;

  /* These dimensions are in reality dynamic and therefore unknown */
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  border-color: green;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1785493/pexels-photo-1785493.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kasuma-1785493.jpg&fm=jpg&w=640&h=960">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1785493/pexels-photo-1785493.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kasuma-1785493.jpg&fm=jpg&w=640&h=960">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS. It has no idea where the focal point is, nor, I suspect would ANY method without manual intervention to state the focal point.

Comment: The focal point coordinates are known. If I would also know the container dimensions I could do it like described here: https://css-tricks.com/focusing-background-image-precise-location-percentages/ But I search for a solution when I don't know the container dimensions.